# Resetting Select Tag in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Here is my HTML code

```
 <select  style="margin-top: 10px;" ng-model="selectedClinic" ng-options="x.name for x in clinics" ng-change="clinicChanged(selectedClinic)"  name="clinicName" id="clinicName"  required>
```

i am adding

All i want is to reset this select tag from controller when ever i need

i am using

```
$scope.selectedClinic = "Default Value";
```

But this add a blank value in select at top and select that

Comment: ng-model of select expects a object and you are passing string......assign object(key,value) and try

Comment: I tried but it still adds a blank value. I just want to reset it to default state as when the page was loaded